# Cannot use F10 key in Midnight commander running in OS X's terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app, midnight-commander

I connect to my server from Terminal in Mac OS X 10.5. When I run Midnight Commander there I cannot use function keys like F10 to close MC even I cannot use mouse to control MC. Any idea why function keys don't work ?

Comment: migrate to serverfault.com?

Comment: Have you tried Function-F10?  By default I believe the F-keys are mapped to the functions.

Comment: Please accept an answer if it satisfies your question, otherwise please follow up with additional requirements/comments.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Don't know why the `Fx` keys don't work, but you can press `Esc`, then `0` to simulate F10. Also works with 1-9 for F1-F9.

Comment: That's solve the same problem even though I'm not in OsX.

Answer (score 11):

Function keys are used to control both software and hardware functions as well as Dashboard and Expose in Mac OS X. If you have a Macbook Pro, F1 and F2 control screen lighting, F10 mutes the speakers, etc.

Check the `Keyboard` preference pane in `System Preferences.app`:

1. Is the checkbox "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" on the "Keyboard tab"  checked? If it's not, you need to press `Fn+F10` for Mac OS to register a `F10` key press. Otherwise, you're just toggling mute speakers (or whatever you have on F10).
2. Check the second tab, "Keyboard Shortcuts", especially "Dashboard & Dock", and "Exposé & Spaces", if F10 is used for one of these functions. If it is, the key press is intercepted before Terminal receives it.

This answer was written for Mac OS X 10.6, I don't know if those dialogs were changed. If step 2 above does not work, check the Dashboard/Expose/Spaces preference pane in System Preferences, the same settings should be available there.

Answer (score 4):

To send F1-F12 keys to an ncurses program running in Terminal.app press `fn`+`command`+`F1…F12`. This works for me on a MacBook Air with OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs because of `ansi` *terminfo*.
You can change declaration to `xterm` in **Terminal Preferences Advanced Tab**  and **fn** keys will work.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to 'System Preferences...' select 'Expose & Spaces' Preference Pane.
- Click on the Expos Tab.
- Change the All Windows Setting to for instance F11
- Change Application Windows Setting to for instance F12
- Change Show Desktop Setting to for instance F13
- Close System Preferences App

And your Terminal is able to respond to the Function Keys correctly and you're able to quit Midnight Commander.